# compiler options on linux box in ifort

Tags: linker, compiler-errors, fortran

I am using ifort and am getting a linking error when I attempt to compile my programs with compiler options.  Nevertheless, I have tested out these options on a very small simple program I get the same issue.

I suspect therefore that it has to do with the way that ifort was installed or the type of system that I am using but I can't be sure.  These programs compile alright when they are compiled with no options. My question is what am I doing wrong is there a way not to have these errors while using the compiler options or the compiler options simply not compatible with the system that I am using.

here is how the program is compiled regularly:

```
 ifort -free  testrealprint.out testrealprint.f90
```

here is how the program is compiled with options:

```
    ifort -free  -O2 -stand f03 -check all -traceback -warn all -fstack-protector -    assume protect_parens -implicitnone testrealprint.out testrealprint.f90
```

here is the very simple code that I am using to test the compiler options:

```
program main 

implicit none

real, dimension(1:3)  :: adremvect
 integer :: j
 character (LEN = 7) :: adremchar, adremcharadj,adremcharadjtrm, adremcharnew 
 adremvect = (/ 2.0, 1.3, 1.0 /)
  do j = 1, 3
        write(adremchar, '(f5.1)') adremvect(j)
        adremcharadj = adjustl(adremchar)
        adremcharadjtrm =  trim(adremcharadj)
         adremcharnew = adremchar(4:)
          print *, adremvect(j), adremcharadj, adremcharadjtrm, adremcharnew
 end do
```

here is part of the error message that i receive when I use the compiler options:

```
testrealprint.out: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first     defined here
  testrealprint.out: In function `_fini':
  (.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first     defined here
   testrealprint.out:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:  (.rodata.cst4+0x0):   first defined here
        testrealprint.out: In function `__data_start':
     (.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
   ld: error in testrealprint.out(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
```

Comment: Are you attempting to have the compiler name the final executable as  `testrealprint.out`?

Comment: yes, i am so attempting.

Answer (score 5):

It looks very much like you are missing a command line option for naming the executable emitted by the compiler. I presume you actually want something like this (note the `-o` option):

```
ifort -free  -O2 -stand f03 -check all -traceback -warn all -fstack-protector -assume protect_parens -implicitnone -o testrealprint.out testrealprint.f90
```

The error you are seeing is probably because you are telling the compiler to try making an executable by compiling `testrealprint.f90` and then linking it with the *existing executable* `testrealprint.out`. This is why you are getting duplicate symbol errors from the linker - you are trying to link an existing application into the current linker call. I am kind of surprised that you are not getting a file not found error when trying the compilation without an existing `testrealprint.out` in the search path....

Comment: yes, that seems to do it. The reason that I am not getting a file not found error is because I already had a test version from a default version in my directory. So your answer makes perfect sense given that.