# P3DFFT compilation - ifort compiler error - "multiple definiton of 'main' "

Tags: linux, compilation, compiler-errors, fft, fftw

I need to compile P3DFFT on multiple computers. The problem is, while it compiles on my personal PC, I'm not able to compile it on the other PC who use different compiler.

---

My PC:

```
mpif90 -g -O2 -I../../include driver_rand.c /home/martin/p3dfft/build/libp3dfft.a -L/home/martin/fftw3/libs -lfftw3 -o driver_rand
```

My `mpif90` version:

```
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010
```

Command on the other computer:

```
mpif90 -g -O2 -I../../include driver_rand.c ../../build/libp3dfft.a -L../../../fftw-3.3.4/.libs -lfftw3 -o driver_rand
```

#### Error:

```
driver_rand.c: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

It's obviously caused by different behaviour of the compiler, which is not able to compile `.c` files:

```
ifort (IFORT) 16.0.1 20151021
```

But when I try to compile it with `mpicc` and to use `mpif90` just for linking, I get another error:

```
mpicc -c -g -O2 -I../../include driver_rand.c ../../build/libp3dfft.a -L../../../fftw-3.3.4/.libs -lfftw3 -o driver_rand.o

mpif90 -g -O2 -I../../include driver_rand.o ../../build/libp3dfft.a -L../../../fftw-3.3.4/.libs -lfftw3 -o driver_rand

/home/bes0030/p3dfft/sample/C/driver_rand.c:67: multiple definition of `main'
/apps/all/ifort/2016.1.150-GCC-4.9.3-2.25/compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.150/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/for_main.o:for_main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/apps/all/ifort/2016.1.150-GCC-4.9.3-2.25/compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.150/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/for_main.o: In function `main':
for_main.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `MAIN__'
```

Now here I'm completely lost - what am I doing wrong this time? I've never seen "multiple definition of main" error before.

---

#### Edit:

I've read those questions, but none of them seems to describe the same problem as I have:

- [compiler options on linux box in ifort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074754/compiler-options-on-linux-box-in-ifort)
- [multiple definition link error in fortran (ifort - gfortran)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059177/multiple-definition-link-error-in-fortran-ifort-gfortran)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the ifort man page](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/linux_clusters/man/ifort.txt), the ifort compiler has a `nofor_main` command line switch:

> ```
> -nofor_main
>          Specifies the main program is not written in Fortran, and  pre-
>          vents  the  compiler from linking for_main.o into applications.
>          The default is -for_main.
> ```

So, as instructed, to link with your `driver_rand.c` file which contains a definition of `main`, you should add the `-nofor_main` option:

```
mpif90 -nofor_main -g -O2 -I../../include driver_rand.o ../../build/libp3dfft.a -L../../../fftw-3.3.4/.libs -lfftw3 -o driver_rand
```